# Candy Machine mintV2: Split Mint fee

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex, candy-machine, solana-program-library

I am trying to mint an NFT using candy machine, I want to split the sol payment received from candy guard. Right now I have set the creators share, How do I split the sol payment on Mint.

```js
const createInstructions = await create(props.umi, {
    candyMachine,
    collectionMint: collectionMint.publicKey,
    collectionUpdateAuthority,
    tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0, // No royalty to market place
    itemsAvailable: nftData.maxSupply, // Increase SOL cost per items. Check the cost on Devnet before launch.
    creators: [
        {
            address: props.umi.identity.publicKey, // creators wallet
            verified: true,
            percentageShare: 95,
        },
        {
            address: "second wallet address", // second wallet
            verified: true,
            percentageShare: 5,
        },
    ],
    configLineSettings: some({
        prefixName: prefixName,
        nameLength: 32-prefixName.length,
        prefixUri: prefixUri,
        uriLength: 200-prefixUri.length,
        isSequential: true,
    }),
    guards: {
        mintLimit: some({ id: 1, limit: nftData.maxMintAmountPerTx }),
        solPayment: some({ lamports: lamports(lamportsPrice), destination: props.umi.identity.publicKey }),
    },
})
```

I want to split 95 percent share to the creator and other 5 percent should go to the second address defined.

While minting using `mintV2`, the whole payment is transferred to a single account i.e. creators account. As I understand creators share will be applicable when there is a secondary sale on this minted NFT. So how do I split the share on minting.

```js
const nftMint =  generateSigner(props.umi)  
const transaction = await transactionBuilder()
    .add(setComputeUnitLimit(props.umi, { units: 800_000 }))
    .add(mintV2(props.umi, {
        candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
        candyGuard: candyGuard.publicKey,
        nftMint,
        collectionMint: props.mintedNft.collectionMintId,
        collectionUpdateAuthority: props.mintedNft.collectionUpdateAuthorityId,
        mintArgs: {
            mintLimit: some({ id: 1 }),
            solPayment: some({destination: candyMachine.authority }),
        },
    })
)
```